# Integrate Mongeez with Spring Boot and Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I want to integrate [Mongeez](https://github.com/secondmarket/mongeez) with my Spring Boot application and was wondering how to properly run Mongeez during application startup. Mongeez [suggests](https://github.com/secondmarket/mongeez/wiki/How-to-use-mongeez) creating a `MongeezRunner` bean. However, the challenge is to run Mongeez before any of the Spring Data initialization is happening, specifically, before the `MongoTemplate` instance is created. This is crucial because there might be changes in the database that prevent the application to start at all (e.g. changing index definitions).

My current approach is to provide the MongoTemplate bean myself, running Mongeez before creating it:

```
@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(Mongo mongo, MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory,
                                   MongoConverter converter) throws IOException {
    // make sure that Mongeez runs before Spring Data is initialized
    runMongeez(mongo);

    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, converter);
}

private void runMongeez(Mongo mongo) throws IOException {
    Mongeez mongeez = new Mongeez();
    mongeez.setMongo(mongo);
    mongeez.setDbName(mongodbDatabaseName);
    mongeez.setFile(new ClassPathResource("/db/migrations.xml"));
    mongeez.process();
}
```

It works, but it feels like a hack. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After taking a look at Spring Boot's source code, it turns out that this problem isn't anything new. The `FlywayAutoConfiguration` for example has to make sure that [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) (a migration tool for SQL-based databases) runs before any `EntityManagerFactory` beans are created. To achieve this the auto-configuration registers a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` that dynamically makes every `EntityManagerFactory` bean depend on the Flyway bean, thus forcing Spring to create the Flyway bean first.

I solved my problem by creating a Spring Boot starter with a similar auto-configuration for Mongeez: [mongeez-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/hzpz/mongeez-spring-boot-starter).